# How to calculate the sub-sum in the objective function? Gurobi optimize

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, gurobi

I need to minimize the following function:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6yG5.png)

> where d_it - binary array: d_it = [[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1,
>   0, 0, 0], ...]
>   x_it - amount up to next 1 from d_it.
>   For example: df
>   = [3763398, 2029384, 2976081, 3269537, 2698083, 2519153, 2415021]
>   if  d_0 = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
>   then
>   x_00 = 3763398 + 2029384 + 2976081, 
>   x_03 = 3269537 + 2698083 + 2519153 + 2415021

```
from gurobipy import *
atm_frame = [[3763398, 2029384, 2976081, 3269537, 2698083, 2519153, 2415021],
             [0, 0, 2447076, 2653185, 2705684, 2836803, 2292156]]

N = 2
T = 7
d = {}
Q = 3
def calc_F(atm_frame):
    F = 0.1017/365
    amount = sum(atm_frame)
    result = 0
    for i in atm_frame:
        result += amount * F
        amount -= i
    return int(result)
#This function finds the window length to the next 1
#Input: atm_num - i, start - t
def find_window(atm_num, start):
    try:
        days = [d[atm_num,t].x for t in range(T)]
    except:
        days = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    print(days)
    win_size = 0
    if start == T-1:
        return 0
    else:
        for i in range(start+1,T):
            if not days[i]:
                win_size += 1
            else:
                break
    return win_size

m = Model('ATM Optimize')

for i in range(N):
    for t in range(T):
        d[i,t] = m.addVar(obj=1, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="d(%s,%s)" % (i,t))

m.addConstr(quicksum(d[i,t] for i in range(N) for t in range(T)) == Q)
m.update()

obj=quicksum(quicksum((calc_F(atm_frame[i][t:t+find_window(i,t)]))*d[i,t] for t in range(T)) for i in range(N))
m.setObjective(obj, GRB.MINIMIZE)
m.optimize()
```

At the first iteration, the variables do not have values.
I tried to set it manually using try / except, but the values of the variables did not appear.
Output:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Optimize a model with 1 rows, 14 columns and 14 nonzeros
Variable types: 0 continuous, 14 integer (14 binary)
Coefficient statistics:
  Matrix range     [1e+00, 1e+00]
  Objective range  [7e+02, 2e+04]
  Bounds range     [1e+00, 1e+00]
  RHS range        [3e+00, 3e+00]
Found heuristic solution: objective 35468.000000
Presolve removed 0 rows and 1 columns
Presolve time: 0.00s
Presolved: 1 rows, 13 columns, 13 nonzeros
Variable types: 0 continuous, 13 integer (12 binary)

Root relaxation: objective 7.010000e+02, 1 iterations, 0.00 seconds

    Nodes    |    Current Node    |     Objective Bounds      |     Work
 Expl Unexpl |  Obj  Depth IntInf | Incumbent    BestBd   Gap | It/Node Time

*    0     0               0     701.0000000  701.00000  0.00%     -    0s

Explored 0 nodes (1 simplex iterations) in 0.02 seconds
Thread count was 8 (of 8 available processors)

Solution count 2: 701 35468 

Optimal solution found (tolerance 1.00e-04)
Best objective 7.010000000000e+02, best bound 7.010000000000e+02, gap 0.0000%
{(0, 0): <gurobi.Var d(0,0) (value -0.0)>, (0, 1): <gurobi.Var d(0,1) (value -0.0)>, (0, 2): <gurobi.Var d(0,2) (value -0.0)>, (0, 3): <gurobi.Var d(0,3) (value -0.0)>, (0, 4): <gurobi.Var d(0,4) (value -0.0)>, (0, 5): <gurobi.Var d(0,5) (value 1.0)>, (0, 6): <gurobi.Var d(0,6) (value 1.0)>, (1, 0): <gurobi.Var d(1,0) (value -0.0)>, (1, 1): <gurobi.Var d(1,1) (value -0.0)>, (1, 2): <gurobi.Var d(1,2) (value -0.0)>, (1, 3): <gurobi.Var d(1,3) (value -0.0)>, (1, 4): <gurobi.Var d(1,4) (value -0.0)>, (1, 5): <gurobi.Var d(1,5) (value -0.0)>, (1, 6): <gurobi.Var d(1,6) (value 1.0)>}
```

Each iteration of the variable's value does not appear, but at the end of the gurobi sets some random values. Is it possible to calculate the amount in another way?

Answer (score 0):

It seem that your d is empty ??? days = [d[atm_num,t].x for t in range(T)]
and what the x ?

Comment: .x extracts the value of a gurobi variable

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem, you can do like delow:

```
from gurobipy import *
atm_frame = [[3763398, 2029384, 2976081, 3269537, 2698083, 2519153, 2415021],
         [0, 0, 2447076, 2653185, 2705684, 2836803, 2292156]]
N = 2
T = 7
#d = {}
d = [[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],\
 [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]]
Q = 3
def calc_F(atm_frame):
   F = 0.1017/365
   amount = sum(atm_frame)
   result = 0
   for i in atm_frame:
     result += amount * F
     amount -= i
   return int(result)
#This function finds the window length to the next 1
#Input: atm_num - i, start - t
def find_window(atm_num, start):
   try:
      days = [d[atm_num][t] for t in range(T)]
   except:
      days = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
   print(days)
   win_size = 0
   if start == T-1:
      return 0
   else:
      for i in range(start+1,T):
        if not days[i]:
            win_size += 1
        else:
            break
   return win_size
m = Model('ATM Optimize')

x={}
for i in range(N):
    for t in range(T):
        x[i,t] = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="d(%s,%s)" % (i,t))
m.addConstr(quicksum(x[i,t] for i in range(N) for t in range(T)) == Q)
m.update()
obj=quicksum(quicksum((calc_F(atm_frame[i][t:t+find_window(i,t)]))*x[i,t] for t in range(T)) for i in range(N))
m.setObjective(obj, GRB.MINIMIZE)
m.optimize()
```

Comment: Why did you add x, if it is not used in the objective function? We need to optimize the variable d_it, not x_it. My problem is that my calculation method does not work for x_it, because d_it is empty

Comment: It does not work. Maybe you did not understand the task. I need to find the optimal value of di for each xi.

Comment: For example: x_i = [3763398, 2029384, 2976081, 3269537, 2698083, 2519153, 2415021] d_i = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]

Comment: If you have to minimize quicksum(x[i,t]*d[i,t] for i in range(N) for t in range(T)), you have give put x[i,t]  like parameter. I dont understand what is the fonction of  find_window(atm_num, start) but i propose those corrections. Can you test them ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 x={}
 for i in range(N):
      for t in range(T):
           x.update({(i,t): atm_frame[i][t]})

 obj=quicksum(quicksum(x[i,t]*d[i,t] for t in range(T)) for i in range(N))
 m.setObjective(obj, GRB.MINIMIZE)
 m.optimize()

 # this  will give you the result in dictionnary  
 if m.SolCount>0 or status == GRB.Status.OPTIMAL:
    sol_d=m.getAttr('x',d)
    D_d={}
    for i in range(N):
       for t in range(T):
          D_d.update({(i,t):sol_d[i,t]})
```

Comment: I understood your idea. But is it possible to calculate the sum x[i][t] between two 1 in d[i]? In my case, d[i][t] is a binary decision variable.    
If d[i][t] is 1, then I consider the sum of x[i][t] up to the next 1.
d[i] = [1, 0, 0, 1]  x[i] = [100, 200, 300, 400]
if d[i][0] = 1 then result[i][0] = sum(x[i][0]+ x[i][1]+ x[i][2])
The objective function will look like this:
minimize quicksum(result[i][t]*d[i][t] for i in range(N) for t in range(T))
I do not understand, is it possible to count this result during iterations?

Comment: If i understand in your exemple, i can say that : d[i] = [1, 0, 0, 1,0,1,0]
         x[i] = [100, 200, 300, 400];
         if d[i][0] = 1   then
               result[i][0] = sum(x[i][0]+ x[i][1]+ x[i][2]) ;       

         if d[i][3] = then     
                 result[i][3] = sum(x[i][3]+ x[i][4])

Comment: ok then, your actual model dont do what you want. Because result is also a variable. You have work on a new model.

Comment: Yes, I understand that it does not work, but I can not figure out how to calculate such amounts. Can you show me an example please?